# Video Conferencing in Freeswitch

Tags: android, ios, webrtc, freeswitch, video-conferencing

I am working on Calling Solution which uses FreeSwitch for Audio/Video Calling. I am stuck with Video Conferencing system that will be run by iOS and Andriod client devices.

- When I create a Video Conference Call, every user can see Video of only one user.
- Then I added some canvas variables for Video Conferencing but all in vain.
- I have also enabled WebRTC port in FreeSwitch.

I need an open source Video Conferencing Solution developed under Freeswitch and WebRTC and will be compatible to develop in Andriod and iOS platforms.

Does OpenVCS or telepresence Server can do trick or not? Any other solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the guide here you will get WebRTC with Verto demo for use in a browser, this works on google chrome for android.

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Debian+8+Jessie

From there you can probably use embedded WebRTC framework and SIP client to make WebRTC clients from something like REACT native.

You can visit the FreeSWITCH community for more info.